# How to read any text after = sign stored in a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am working on some batch file.
I need to read name from some text file. Let me explain it

I have one file `File.txt`, which has entry like `FirstName=John`.
Now my batch file should read text `John` from the file and I should be able store `John` in some variable too.

But with following code, if I use `delims==`,I can get `FirstName` text stored in some variable but not `John`.

```
for /F "delims==" %%I in (File.txt) do set Title=%%I
echo %Title%
```

Is there any way where I can get `John` from my `File.txt` and store it with in my `for` loop ?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (File.txt) do set Title=%%b
echo %Title%
```

Does extract the first name value into `Title`... but only for the last line containing `Firstname`!

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (File.txt) do (
    set t=%t% %%b
)
echo %t:Firstname=%
```

Does concatenate all first names found.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that `John` is the second token found, `Firstname` being the first token found. You have many options.

- You can use `tokens=2` to skip the first token and get only the second token into variable `%%I`. No other variable is generated.
- You can use variable `%%J` (which is automatically generated) which contains the second token. `%%K` would contain the 3rd token and so forth.
- You can use `tokens=2*` to skip the first token and get all following tokens into variables `I`, `J`, `K`, etc.